# Add a bound click handler to a UWP TextBlock control

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

In UWP, how do I define a TextBlock so when it's clicked it calls a method in my view model?

```
    <TextBlock Text="Click Me">
    </TextBlock>
```

I know in Xamarin there are GestureRecognizers you can add to a Label, so looking for something equivalent in UWP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In UWP, you can subscribe the [Tapped](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.tapped?view=winrt-19041) event. when you click the area of UIElement, the event will be triggered. For example:

.xaml:

```
<TextBlock Text="Click Me" Tapped="TextBlock_Tapped">
</TextBlock>
```

.cs:

```
private void TextBlock_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //Call the method of your viewmodel
}
```

You can also bind the method of your viewmodel with the Tapped event directly.